# What is right way to create upgradable classes

Tags: python, oop

I try to made easy upgradable classes. Idea in following: I have an instance of class "Person", which has to be converted to another class "Worker" by instantiation using object of class "Person". The main conditions:

1. "Person" is parent class of "Worker"
2. **init** functions are differents from each other

Now I wrote below code. But I wondering: if it is possible to change redundant properties declarations at "Worker" class to something more simple, because base class "Person" can be extended any time, and I don't want to write duplicated code.

And what is best practice to achieve same goal?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, row: dict = None):
        if not row:
            row = {}
        self.first_name = row.get('first_name', None)
        self.last_name = row.get('last_name', None)
        # here goes many properties


class Worker(Person):
    def __init__(self, person: Person):
        super().__init__()
        self.position = 'unemployed'
        # below code which I want to make independent from base class properties
        self.first_name = person.first_name
        self.last_name = person.last_name
        # here goes many properties of base class


person_info = {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe'}
person = Person(person_info)
worker = Worker(person)
print(f'{worker.first_name} {worker.last_name} is {worker.position}')
```

Comment: what you meant is polymorphisim

Comment: "if it is possible to change redundant properties declarations at "Worker" class to something more simple" I don't understand what you mean here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I meant that I want to get rid from duplicated properties declarations in "Worker" class i.e.: **self.first_name = person.first_name**

Comment: @Carcigenicate although, often you would use a `classmethod`

Comment: why not `super().__init__({"first_name":person.first_name, "last_name": person.last_name})`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Idk why, but I like `staticmethod` more. I actually haven't run into a case where using `cls` is neater than referring to the class directly, but I barely ever use inheritance, so I may be missing an edge case where `classmethod` is superior.

Comment: @Carcigenicate well, because then the method returns an instance of the subclass when you subclass it. Because it gets a reference to the current class, instead of hard-coding `Worker`, of course, that may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, that actually makes sense. Thanks for the perspective.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga problem is that I already have huge list of objects "Person", and some of them I need to "upgrade" to "Worker" class. So at time of "Person" instantiation I don't know whether it will be "Worker" or not.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and also the main goal is to get rid of enumeration of all Base class properties, if they already exists. Are there something like copy function? Which can copy only same named properties between classes?

Comment: @yogom30110 yes, but I'm not casting child class to it's parent. On the contrary I need to cast parent class object to it's child class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
class Worker(Parent):
    def __init__(self, person: Person):
        vars(self).update(vars(person))
        self.position = 'unemployed'
```

Seems pointless to call `super().__init__()`.

Note, the above will only work with a non-slotted class.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm already found another way: **self.__dict__.update(person.__dict__)**

Comment: @Yurik that is the exact same as above, `vars(obj)` is just `obj.__dict__`

Comment: By the way - what is wrong with my question, why it received minuses? I made wrong title? Or the question was too broad? Because I tried to understand what is best practice to do this